# Why does this recursion code work?

Tags: python, function, recursion, arguments

```
def permutation(li,result=[]):
    print(li, result)               # I added this print statement as a diagnostic.
    if li == [] or li == None:      # As coded, I expected each recursive call to
        return                      # reinitialize 'result=[]' because there is no
                                    # second argument being passed in the recursive
    if len(li) == 1:                # call below.
        result.append(li[0])
        print(''.join(result))
        result.pop()
        return

    for i in range(0,len(li)):
        result.append(li[i])
        permutation(li[:i] + li[i+1:])          # I would have thought that the
       #permutation(li[:i] + li[i+1:], result)  # recursive call needed to be this.
        result.pop()        

test=list('123')
permutation(test)
```

Results:

```
['1', '2', '3'] []
['2', '3'] ['1']
['3'] ['1', '2']
123
['2'] ['1', '3']
132
['1', '3'] ['2']
['3'] ['2', '1']
213
```

Comment: The key when using default arguments is that the default value is referencing the same list each time not constructing a new one.  And since lists are mutable, that list is not the same from call to call.

Answer (score 1):

because `result` is a [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument) list. to put it simply, if you append items to a list, the item is still there unless the list or the item is garbage-collected. in your code, `result` points to same list object that is declared as a default argument of `permutation` function. you do not build a new list for `result` upon every call of `permutation` function. Because you push/pop item(s) for every permutation, you might think(and it looks like) your function is 'stateless', but it is not.